# Execute bash snippets directly in shell?

Tags: bash, shell

Is there any way to execute small bash **snippets** in the shell?

If you don't want to edit a file again and again and test it by executing it again and again (in fact by jumping forth and back between two programs: editor and shell), you might want to execute small code snippets (maybe as strings) in the shell directly.

For example testing a regular expression or any part of an if-condition: `"hi =~ "h"`. OK, the result of this might be obvious, but there are more complicated cases for one, two or three liner.

---

So, none of [these ways](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119612/executing-bash-shell-scripts), because, AFAIK `bash -x` executes files and `eval` executes commands only.

Comment: If you're running Bash you can literally write the code at the prompt; can you be clearer about what you've tried and why it isn't adequate for you?

Comment: mhm, how can I achive that? I mean, apart from `echo "hi"`, e.g. smth like `if [ "hi" == "hi" ] then echo "this is true" fi` of course does not work (like the equivalent in JS would work in a browser console.

Comment: You're missing semicolons before then & fi.

Comment: Albeit indeed a strange one, how this question is actually "off-topic" would be worth a stringent government investigation... ;) Also, the downvoters may not have understood that "funny, how is this even possible?" is _not_ a good reason for downvoting. (It looks more like they acted by an atavistic fight-or-flight reflex erring on the coward side...)

Comment: @lunakid I think that learning is sometimes not really attractive for people, who have already learned that stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run it in the shell, for example like:

```
$ for i in $(find /etc -type f); do wc -l $i; done
```

This runs through /etc and gives out the line count of each file.

Added according your comment:

```
$ if [ "hi" == "hi" ]; then echo "this is true"; fi
```